# .Net Framework and .Net Core in same solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, coreclr

I have an application targeting .NET Framework, and now I need to develop a library in .NET Core.
I plan to put both projects in the same solution and add the .NET Core library as a reference in the .NET Framework project.

Can this be done? If the answer is yes, how can this be done?

Comment: I don't know whether this can be done; my guess is "no."  But if you're using source control of some sort, you could copy the library to a separate directory in source control, check it out, modify the project type, and pull *that* project into your solution, then keep the two projects in sync via source control...

Comment: It is not possible to reference a xproj from a csproj directly.
You have possiblty to Deploy the xproj as a NuGet package and use the NuGet package in your csproj.

Comment: Every time I modify the code of the library I have to build it, create the NuGet package, unintall the current version and than install the new one in the .Net Framework project, right ?

Comment: .NET Standard provide common platform for Asp.Net Core, Asp.Net Framework and Xamarin. Some helpful links
[Intoducing .Net Standard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/)
[Msdn .Net Standard][2] [2]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Answer (score 26):

There is an article published in April 2017 on how to support both runtimes from the same solution:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/project-structure

It boils down to 2 methods:

- Having both frameworks configured in the same project (e.g. *.csproj):

Replace existing projects with a multi-targeted .NET Core project.

- Having a separate project for each framework:

Keep existing projects and create a .NET Core project.

---

We are actively discussing which way to go in pythonnet, since the project supports .NET Framework on Windows and Mono on Linux/OSX. Now we are adding cross-platform pythonnet support:

https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/pull/518